# Matplotlib - Contourf - How to have a non-uniform ticks spacing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot contourf with (lat,depth,temp) and then have similar spacing as in the figure below (the temperature vary more near the surface then at depth, so I want to emphasized this region).

My depth array is not uniform (i.e. depth = [5,15,...,4975,5185,...]. I want to have such non-uniform vertical spacing.

I would like to show yticks = [10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,5000], and depth array does not have those exact values.

```
z   = np.arange(0,50)                       # I want uniform spacing
pos = ([0,2,5,10,15,20,30,40,48])           # I want some yticks (not all of them)

ax=plt.contourf(lat,z,temp)                 # temp is a variable with dimensions (lat,depth)
plt.colorbar()

plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks(pos)              # Set some yticks, not all of them
plt.yticks(z[pos],depth[pos].astype(int))   # Replace the dummy values of z-array by something meaningful

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.grid(linestyle=':')
plt.gca().set(ylabel='depth (m)',xlabel='Latitude')'''
```

Potential Temperature of the Atlantic Ocean:
[image: Potential Temperature of the Atlantic Ocean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the matplotlib docs on [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html), you can specify the labels you want to use. In your case, if you want to show the labels `[10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,5000]` you can simply pass that list as the second argument in `plt.yticks()`, like so

```
plt.yticks(z[pos], [10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,5000])
```

and it will display the `yticks` accordingly. The issue arises in the specification of the positions - since the `depth` array does not have points corresponding exactly to the desired `ytick` values you will need to interpolate in order to find the exact position at which to place the labels. Unless the approximate positions specified in `pos` are already sufficient, in which case the above suffices.

If the `depth` data are not uniformly spaced then you can use `numpy.interp` to perform the interpolation, as shown below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create some depth data that is not uniformly spaced over [0, 5500]
depth = [(np.random.random() - 0.5)*25 + ii for ii in np.linspace(0, 5500, 50)]

lat = np.linspace(-75, 75, 50)
z   = np.linspace(0,50, 50)
yticks = [10,100,500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,5000]

# Interpolate depths to get z-positions
pos = np.interp(yticks, depth, z)

temp = np.outer(lat, z)        # Arbitrarily populate temp for demonstration
ax  = plt.contourf(lat,z,temp)
plt.colorbar()

plt.gca().yaxis.set_ticks(pos)
plt.yticks(pos,yticks)         # Place yticks at interpolated z-positions

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.grid(linestyle=':')
plt.gca().set(ylabel='Depth (m)',xlabel='Latitude')
plt.show()
```

This will find the *exact* positions where the `yticks` *would* fall if the `depth` array had data at those positions and place them accordingly as shown below.

[image: Output with interpolated ytick positions]